# How to hide an element when accessing site as a PWA

Tags: javascript, css, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a site and want to use it as a PWA (Progressive Web App) as well.

But I want to hide specific elements in the PWA.

This is the section I want to hide:

```html
<section class="py-5 border-bottom noShowApp" id="features">
```

I have tried the CSS approach:

```css
@media all and (display-mode: standalone) {
  .noShowApp {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And the JS approach:

```js
function isRunningStandalone() {
  return (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);
}

if (isRunningStandalone()) {
  alert('hi');
  hide(document.getElementById('features'));
}
```

I get my 'alert' in the app, but the section I want to hide is not hidden....

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to get any of these methods (CSS or JS) to work. I prefer the CSS approach, but if that's not possible, JS will do just fine.

Comment: Have you checked (inspected) the element through the DevTools to see whether there are conflicting CSS rules applied to this element? Maybe try adding an !important next  to display none to see whether your rule takes precedence over other display rules.

Comment: How can I use DevTools when in the App? When I remove the mediaquery (so .noShowApp is always display: none), it works. Then this section is hidden on the normal site, but not in the App.

Comment: Maybe drop the `all` from the media query? https://web.dev/learn/pwa/app-design/#media-queries

Comment: perhaps you miss an extra `}`?

Answer (score 2):

Replying directly to your title question (because you messed up the title and the content of the question)

> How to disable a DIV when accessing site through PWA?

```css
@media all and (display-mode: standalone) {
  #divId {
    display: none
  }
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode) regarding display mode as `standalone`

> The application will look and feel like a standalone application. This can include the application having a different window, its own icon in the application launcher, etc. In this mode, the user agent will exclude UI elements for controlling navigation, but can include other UI elements such as a status bar.

In the `manifest.json` you must have

```json
{
  (...)
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation":"portrait"
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different to the OP's approach? The only visible difference being that the OP used a class and you're using an ID.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes the OP is trying to solve a CSS problem that has nothing to do with `How to disable a DIV when accessing site through PWA`. I simply answered that question: `How to disable a DIV when accessing site through PWA`

Comment: I have suggested an edit, including to the title; it would now match the question itself, reading "How to hide an element when accessing site as a PWA".

Comment: What I am saying is that the OP has already used code basically identical to what you have provided, and it did not work. There is more happening here than just that, but the OP has not provided more details.